# Windows XP only boots when installation CD is in the drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, compact-disc

I have had a few problems with my PC lately. The most recent is that Windows XP will only completely boot if the XP installation CD is also in the drive.

Without CD:

- PC boots until Windows XP splashscreen comes up
- Screen goes black
- 3 1/4" drive flashes (yes, I still have one of those!)
- Pale blue "Windows setup is restarting......." screen appears
- Computer hangs until it is turned off or reset

With CD:

- After the BIOS message "Press any key to boot from CD..." appears
- After a few seconds the screen goes black
- Windows XP splashscreen comes up
- Windows login page comes up and Windows works normally

I tried the suggestion on http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/xp-pro-only-boots-with-installation-cd-214860.html (run `sfc /scannow`) and although it did copy a few files from the CD it didn't fix my problem.

My other recent issues (for elimination purposes):

- Couldn't boot XP after AVG update (same pale blue screen as above)

  - Temporary fix by renaming one AVG `.sys` file
- Hard drive access was very slow, all sound was very choppy

  - Windows had changed my hard drive access from DMA (Direct Memory Access) to PIO (Programmed Input Output), essentially running all HDD data through the CPU
  - Removed IDE device/driver, Windows reinstalled it setting it back to DMA, HDD access is back to normal now